# What is the best way to copy files and directories in batch

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, batch-processing

In part of my script I need to copy a few directories with a lot of data, and the subdirectories as well. Here is what I'm using now:

```
xcopy /e %CD%Migration\testCopy C:\testcopy
```

The thing is, it's asking me a question while the script is running:

*Does C:\testcopy specify a file name or directory name on the target (F = file, D = directory)?*

How can I avoid this question, or maybe there's a better way to copy files and folders using batch?

Comment: Look at command line options (XCOPY /?), in particular, the option /I.  Also, if you append a backslash to the target name, I think it will be assumed to be a directory (C:\testcopy\)

Comment: I use `/I` all the time so that I don't have to worry about whether the path (usually a variable and often obtained from some other source—not known when I'm writing the script) has a trailing dirsep or not.

Comment: i found something that called `robocopy`

Comment: Any idea how display the free memory of a spesific drive so it will return a value which i can compare ?

Comment: No reason to use robocopy, unless you prefer, xcopy is fine for your job. Look at xcopy options, as @Joe suggests. [*Here*](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) is a good explanation. See /S and /I and examples. While at site, look at these commands which all deal with disk usage: FSUTIL.EXE, DISKUSE, FREEDISK.

Comment: Which parameter should i add to the xcopy in order to overwrite the file without answering any questions?   What is the difference between xcopy and robocopy

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
mkdir C:\testcopy 2> nul
```

The "nul" part will prevent the "directory already exists" message.

Comment: In the same script I'm trying to add another script to the `runOnce` , so when the machine make a reboot it will execute it, but id doesn't reboot and right after the 1st script has finished it is automatically starting the 2nd script. Any idea why?